# jsonp issue with FlickrAPI: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrApi is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am not sure why I keep getting the following error.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrApi is not defined`

I am trying to pass an object containing URL parameters to the ajax call.

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3vRM3/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  default: {
    photos: '',
    stat: ''   
  }
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: TheModel,

  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/'

});

// The main view
var List = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.js-container',

  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new TheCollection();

    return this;
  },

  render: function () {
    var self = this;

    var urlParameters = {
        page : '1',
        api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        tags: "candy",
        method: 'flickr.photos.search',
        per_page: '3',
        format: 'json',
        jsoncallback: '?'
    };

    this.collection.fetch({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: urlParameters,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(self.collection);

        }
    });

    return this;
  }

});


var myList= new List();
myList.render();
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="DropdownList">
  <% console.log('this is the template') %>
  <h3>Stat = <%- collection[0].stat %></h3>
</script>

<div class="js-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the response:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":144580,"perpage":3,"total":"433738","photo":[{"id":"13721741393","owner":"31558746@N00","secret":"1965a3793c","server":"5117","farm":6,"title":"Candy corn","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"13721755993","owner":"31558746@N00","secret":"c4eb729500","server":"2938","farm":3,"title":"Candy corn","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"13722064924","owner":"31558746@N00","secret":"b8662de0bb","server":"3723","farm":4,"title":"7-Layer Candy Dip","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
```

they are using JSONP and setting the callback to `jsonFlickrApi`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how to set your callback.

```
$.ajax(url, { dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: 'jsoncallback' })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log('success (promises): ' + data.name);
}, function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('failed (promises): ' + error);
});
```

By setting jsonp: 'jsoncallback' you get access to the callback stuff.